# How to depend on a Puppet class before mounting?

Tags: puppet

I mount Cloudfuse to access Rackspace's Cloudfiles using Puppet, but on a new host, mount runs too soon, even though I require the whole class. In *Pro Puppet*, James recommends splitting class definitions like this:

```
class cloudfuse{
  include cloudfuse::install, cloudfuse::service, cloudfuse::config
}

class cloudfuse::install{
  # download and install
}

class cloudfuse::config{
  file{'/root/.cloudfuse':
    notify => Class['cloudfuse::service'],
  }
}

class cloudfuse::service{
  service{'cloudfuse':
    ensure => running,
  }
}
```

That works just fine. When I'm ready to mount, I require the top-level, parent class, like this:

```
exec{'mount /data/cloudfiles':
  command => "/usr/local/bin/cloudfuse /data/cloudfiles",
  require => [
    File['/data/cloudfiles'],
    Class['cloudfuse'],
  ]
}
```

Questions are:

1. Is this idiomatic? I've seen this elsewhere, so I'd say it is.
2. Should I actually require `cloudfuse::install` instead of the parent?

I know that requiring `cloudfuse::install` will fix my problem, but if I have a very simple class, maybe I won't split in three like this, then I'd have to guess / look at the manifest to know how to declare the dependency.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclosure, I am one of the developers of Puppet.

Unfortunately, a bug in Puppet means that a class that only contains other classes doesn't cause transitive dependencies.  You can use [the "anchor" pattern](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Anchor_Pattern) to work around that, or you can add an otherwise meaningless resource to the top level class, as in:

```
class cloudfuse {
  include cloudfuse::install, ...
  notify { "hate #8040": message => "work around bug #8040" }
}
```

You can follow [bug #8040](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/8040) to watch for when we finally get this fixed.

Comment: I don't really understand where anchors are coming from? They must be a type, but I don't see any implementation of it, or references to it from http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html

Comment: They are part of the `puppet-stdlib` module at https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib or available on the forge.  That link to the pattern page is a wiki, feel free to update it, or I will try to remember to make the link tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I updated the wiki http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/puppet/wiki/Anchor_Pattern/history